# RadioButton inside RadDropDownTree

Tags: telerik

In my application, the user should select only one child node from each parent node so i have to implement a radiobutton inside RadDropDowntree.
i have implemented a raddropdowntree but with checkboxes, i didn't found Radiobutton template or something
For example
*Color
-White
-Blue 
- Red
*capacity
-250 Go
-500 Go

in this case the user should select only blue +250 Go 
So any Idea ?!

My source Code :
`<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="RadDropDownTree1" runat="server" Width="350px"`
`CheckBoxes="SingleCheck" EnableFiltering="true"  DataFieldID="id"`DataFieldParentID="parentId" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource5"  DataTextField="text" `DataValueField="id"  onnodedatabound="RadDropDownTree1_NodeDataBound"`ondatabound="RadDropDownTree1_DataBound"> 
 `</telerik:RadDropDownTree>`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired check/uncheck effect by setting **CheckBoxes="SingleCheck"**.

See these article and demo for more information:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree-functionality-checkboxes.html
and
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree/examples/applicationscenarios/imagereview/defaultcs.aspx